# YouTube-style search results in UWP XAML

Tags: c#, api, uwp, youtube

I'm working on a YouTube app for the Windows store using UWP and C#. I am familiar with working with Google Data APIs and fetching results from YouTube, but my XAML is not so good.

Could anyone show me a data template I could use to show search results which would display like YouTube does, where it wouldn't end up with the search results going off the page.

The screenshot below is from TubeCast, which is similar to what I need.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6D42v.jpg

Basically I know how to use data templates, but I can't seem to get the XAML stying right to display something similar to this which will auto adjust based on screen size. Cany anybody help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For adaptive ur gridview better to screen change use **AdaptiveGridView** from **uwp community toolkit** (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/adaptivegridview)

and secondly following are some docs to help you with **data template you want**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/item-containers-templates

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/item-templates-listview

Comment: I don't have any XAML code yet as my XAML knowledge is poor at best. I basically need a YouTube-style view where the user is shown results from YouTube including the video title and a thumbnail. Fetching the results isn't a problem, I just need a good looking way to output those results to the user

Comment: then I think you should first practice basic xaml and then move to this , because this is some advance xaml stuff. @user3733885

Answer (score 0):

> I don't have any XAML code yet as my XAML knowledge is poor at best. I basically need a YouTube-style view where the user is shown results from YouTube including the video title and a thumbnail.

@user3733885 I've checked your question and comments on @touseefbsb's reply. As touseefbsb said, the AdaptiveGridView control will meet your requirement about "auto adjust based on screen size". You could directly use this control followed the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/adaptivegridview).

Then, how to make a DataTemplate that will look like your screenshot? It's just a basic XAML layout technology. I've made a simple code sample for your reference:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PhotosTemplate" x:DataType="local:VideoDetail">
        <StackPanel>
            <Image Source="{x:Bind Videoimage}" Stretch="UniformToFill"></Image>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind title}"></TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Background="White">

                <Ellipse Width="30" Height="30" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="{x:Bind Header}"></ImageBrush>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="&#xE890;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="50 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Views}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="&#xE787;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Time}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5 0 0 0"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <controls:AdaptiveGridView Name="AdaptiveGridViewControl"
                               ItemsSource="{x:Bind VideoDetails}"
                               ItemHeight="220"
                               DesiredWidth="300"
                               OneRowModeEnabled="False"
                               SelectionMode="Single"
                               IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                               ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PhotosTemplate}"/>
</Grid>
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<VideoDetail> VideoDetails { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        VideoDetails = new ObservableCollection<VideoDetail>();
        for (int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            VideoDetails.Add(new VideoDetail() {Videoimage=new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/panda.jpg")),Header=new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/monkey.jpg")),Name="author",title="this is a video from test website",Time=DateTime.Now.Day.ToString(),Views=9000 });

        }
    }
}

public class VideoDetail
{
    public BitmapImage Videoimage { get; set;}

    public BitmapImage Header { get; set; }

    public string title { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int Views { get; set; }

    public string Time { get; set; }
}
```

[image]